# How to add stroke around whole circle and animate to rotate circle in svg?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

Here is my jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/q611wenr/4/

Now i need to add stroke around the whole green color circle.

If i add like this: `stroke ="#000" stroke-width="2"` .. it shows text only having stroke..

I need like this one http://s23.postimg.org/w1yktgeuj/Untitled_1.png

And also have to rotating dynamically, i mean not whole circle only rotate that 6 parts within the green color circle.

I am new to using `SVG`, so can anyone help me?

May i know how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You already know how to do a circle - you have a red one on the middle. Duplicate and adapt to get a surrounding circle.

Comment: "Rotating dynamically" will need to be further defined. It's not clear exactly what rotation you want, or when.

Comment: okay @Roamer-1888: one problem may solved.. It rotate dynamically, that six section.. whether it is clock-wise or anti-clock-wise .. its not a problem. thanks

Comment: Direction of rotation is only one factor. For example, do you want continuous rotation, if so what speed, or do you want to a drag-rotate action? As well as specifying it better, you'll also need to demonstrate some kind of effort on the rotation.

Comment: @Roamer-1888: speed means, its normal . and continuous rotation.. thanks....

Comment: when i hover an one part, it will need to stop,, these are process, how to start.. i just blank @Roamer-1888.

Comment: I don't know either. I'm trying to teach you how to write a better question.

Comment: @rish.. please see my edited answer, hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As paul already showed how to draw a stroke, I would continue with his answer to show how to rotate and stop on hover. see this: http://jsfiddle.net/q611wenr/7/

I have used this css rule:

```
svg:not(:hover) {
  -webkit-animation: rotateClockwiseAnimation 5s linear infinite;
  /* Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation: rotateClockwiseAnimation 5s linear infinite;
  /* Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation: rotateClockwiseAnimation 5s linear infinite;
  /* Opera 12+ */
  animation: rotateClockwiseAnimation 5s linear infinite;
}
```

```css
.frag {
  fill: green;
  stroke: #FFFFFF;
  transition: fill 0.3s;
}
.center {
  fill: red;
  width: 50%;
}
a:hover .frag {
  fill: #FFC722;
}
text {
  font-size: 5px;
  fill: #fff;
}
.mid-up-left {
  -ms-transform: rotate(-38deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-38deg);
  transform: rotate(-38deg);
}
.mid-up-right {
  -ms-transform: rotate(38deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(38deg);
  transform: rotate(38deg);
}
.mid-down-left {
  -ms-transform: rotate(38deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(38deg);
  transform: rotate(38deg);
}
.mid-down-right {
  -ms-transform: rotate(-25deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-25deg);
  transform: rotate(-25deg);
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotateClockwiseAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes rotateClockwiseAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-o-keyframes rotateClockwiseAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes rotateClockwiseAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
svg:not(:hover) {
  -webkit-animation: rotateClockwiseAnimation 5s linear infinite;
  /* Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation: rotateClockwiseAnimation 5s linear infinite;
  /* Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation: rotateClockwiseAnimation 5s linear infinite;
  /* Opera 12+ */
  animation: rotateClockwiseAnimation 5s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="500" viewBox="-2 -2 202 203" shape-rendering="geometricPrecision">
  <a xlink:href="#">
    <path class="frag" d="M100,100 v-100 a100,100 1 0,1 86.6025,50" />
    <text x="135" y="-60.5" text-anchor="middle" class='mid-up-right'>Endorsements</text>
  </a>
  <a xlink:href="#">
    <path class="frag" d="M100,100 l86.6025,-50 a100,100 1 0,1 0,100" />
    <text x="185" y="105" text-anchor="middle">personal life</text>
  </a>
  <a xlink:href="#">
    <path class="frag" d="M100,100 l86.6025,50 a100,100 1 0,1 -86.6025,50" />
    <text x="50" y="222" text-anchor="middle" class='mid-down-right'>Place I am visited</text>
  </a>
  <a xlink:href="#">
    <path class="frag" d="M100,100 v100 a100,100 1 0,1 -86.6025,-50" />
    <text x="145" y="108" text-anchor="middle" class='mid-down-left'>Academy</text>
  </a>
  <a xlink:href="#">
    <path class="frag" d="M100,100 l-86.6025,50 a100,100 1 0,1 0,-100" />
    <text x="15" y="105" text-anchor="middle">awards</text>
  </a>
  <a xlink:href="#">
    <path class="frag" d="M100,100 l-86.6025,-50 a100,100 1 0,1 86.0025,-50" />
    <text x="25" y="60.5" text-anchor="middle" class='mid-up-left'>Career Overview</text>
  </a>
  <a xlink:href="#">
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="20" stroke="red" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  </a>
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2" fill="none" />
</svg>
```

Well, as you can see, this solution does the rotation and also stops the animation on hover, but there is a problem that, it does not stop at the point where it was hovered, instead it stops at the initial point.

---

So you can still overcome this problem, see this: http://jsfiddle.net/q611wenr/8/

I have used   `animation-play-state: paused`, to pause the rotation.

```css
.frag {
  fill: green;
  stroke: #FFFFFF;
  transition: fill 0.3s;
}
.center {
  fill: red;
  width: 50%;
}
a:hover .frag {
  fill: #FFC722;
}
text {
  font-size: 5px;
  fill: #fff;
}
.mid-up-left {
  -ms-transform: rotate(-38deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-38deg);
  transform: rotate(-38deg);
}
.mid-up-right {
  -ms-transform: rotate(38deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(38deg);
  transform: rotate(38deg);
}
.mid-down-left {
  -ms-transform: rotate(38deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(38deg);
  transform: rotate(38deg);
}
.mid-down-right {
  -ms-transform: rotate(-25deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-25deg);
  transform: rotate(-25deg);
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotateClockwiseAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes rotateClockwiseAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-o-keyframes rotateClockwiseAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes rotateClockwiseAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
svg {
  -webkit-animation: rotateClockwiseAnimation 5s linear infinite;
  /* Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation: rotateClockwiseAnimation 5s linear infinite;
  /* Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation: rotateClockwiseAnimation 5s linear infinite;
  /* Opera 12+ */
  animation: rotateClockwiseAnimation 5s linear infinite;
}
svg:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused
}
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="500" viewBox="-2 -2 202 203" shape-rendering="geometricPrecision">
  <a xlink:href="#">
    <path class="frag" d="M100,100 v-100 a100,100 1 0,1 86.6025,50" />
    <text x="135" y="-60.5" text-anchor="middle" class='mid-up-right'>Endorsements</text>
  </a>
  <a xlink:href="#">
    <path class="frag" d="M100,100 l86.6025,-50 a100,100 1 0,1 0,100" />
    <text x="185" y="105" text-anchor="middle">personal life</text>
  </a>
  <a xlink:href="#">
    <path class="frag" d="M100,100 l86.6025,50 a100,100 1 0,1 -86.6025,50" />
    <text x="50" y="222" text-anchor="middle" class='mid-down-right'>Place I am visited</text>
  </a>
  <a xlink:href="#">
    <path class="frag" d="M100,100 v100 a100,100 1 0,1 -86.6025,-50" />
    <text x="145" y="108" text-anchor="middle" class='mid-down-left'>Academy</text>
  </a>
  <a xlink:href="#">
    <path class="frag" d="M100,100 l-86.6025,50 a100,100 1 0,1 0,-100" />
    <text x="15" y="105" text-anchor="middle">awards</text>
  </a>
  <a xlink:href="#">
    <path class="frag" d="M100,100 l-86.6025,-50 a100,100 1 0,1 86.0025,-50" />
    <text x="25" y="60.5" text-anchor="middle" class='mid-up-left'>Career Overview</text>
  </a>
  <a xlink:href="#">
    <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="20" stroke="red" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  </a>
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" stroke="#000" stroke-width="2" fill="none" />
</svg>
```

here is the code:

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotateClockwiseAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes rotateClockwiseAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@-o-keyframes rotateClockwiseAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
@keyframes rotateClockwiseAnimation {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
svg {
  -webkit-animation: rotateClockwiseAnimation 5s linear infinite;
  /* Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation: rotateClockwiseAnimation 5s linear infinite;
  /* Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation: rotateClockwiseAnimation 5s linear infinite;
  /* Opera 12+ */
  animation: rotateClockwiseAnimation 5s linear infinite;
}

svg:hover{
    animation-play-state: paused
}
```

Comment: thanks lot @naeem: but still have to change little bit.. that two text are didn't transform right? 1. personal life and 2.awards... and also align of all the texts are not properly.. thanks.

Comment: @rish you can post another question, that will let you gain more users try solve your problem.. also let me know if you post another question

Comment: if we look at closer, why these two texts are 1.place i am visited and 2.academy, placed different from others right?..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71754/discussion-between-naeem-shaikh-and-rish).

Answer (score 1):

Just add a new circle to the end of your SVG:

```
<circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" stroke ="#000" stroke-width="2" fill="none"/>
```

[Demo fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/q611wenr/5/)

Comment: What have you tried re rotation?  There are numerous tutorials on the web on how to do rotation and other transforms.  StackOverflow is for help with problems you can't solve by yourself.

Comment: Sorry if I sounded mean, but if you google "svg animation rotation" you get nearly half a million hits. :)

Comment: thats all about like earth rotation... i need to know, within my circle, that 6 section have to rotate. @paul: